# Let $u_1 = (1,a,0)$, $u_2 = (1,2,2)$, $u_3 = (a-2,3,0)$ where $a$ is a real number.

Tags: linear-algebra

(I) There are infinitely many values of $a$ that will make {$u_1,u_2,u_3$} a basis for $\mathbb{R^3}$.

(II) There are only two values of $a$ that will make {$u_1,u_2,u_3$} a linearly independent set.

Which of the above statements is/are true?

I put my answer (I) as the only true statement, but kind of unsure. Can anyone here advise me on how I can approach this question? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Guide:

Consider the determinant $\begin{vmatrix} 1 & a & 0 \\ 1 & 2 & 2 \\ a-2 & 3 & 0 \end{vmatrix}$.

Figure out when is the determinant equal to non-zero. You might like to start by expanding along the third column and you will get a quadratic expression.